# How to adjust the icon size of a QStandardItem? (QStandardItem has no setIconSize() method)

Tags: c++, qt, icons

Is it possible to increase the icon size of a QStandardItem? I have icons on some columns of a QStandardItemModel (and the columns are QStandardItems). I simply want to make the icons bigger. I've made sure that there is enough space to accommodate a bigger icon by using sizeHint(); the icon is now much smaller than the space available.

I've tried multiple ways to make sure the icon itself is big, including using a bigger .png file and also by making the QIcon out of a QPixmap whose size I've set manually. Either way the size stays the same so I feel the problem lies within QStandardItem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Checked `QAbstractItemView::iconSize`?

Comment: @replete Sorry, not sure what you're getting at. How can I use that function here?

Comment: If the items are being visualized by a view that derives from `QAbstractItemView` (e.g. `QTreeView`), then perhaps that property of the view is constraining your icons. I don't know whether this is the case or not, but it is something you could easily check.